# Snowflake creation of Notification integration on azure storage queue error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I was trying to create notification integration for azure storage , created storage queue. snowflake Subnet included and snowflake service principle has access to storage , Everything working fine with storage integration. now i am trying to setup notification integration and getting following error

SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 370001:1831050371;

````
create notification integration my_azure_int
enabled = true
type = queue
notification_provider = azure_storage_queue
azure_storage_queue_primary_uri = 'https://accountname.queue.core.windows.net/queuename'
azure_tenant_id = '123456-abcdef-abc-123-98765432';```

Error is not at all descriptive. please suggest some ideas.
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify how many notification integrations you have created in your account by executing the below command?

```
show notification integrations;
```

This could be because you exceeded the maximum number of integrations/queues that can be created (10 in total).

If it's not the case, I'd suggest trying again later, or open a support ticket.

Comment: I'm creating notification integration for first time. I though of posting it once here before creating case. 

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It is issue with snowflake for some reason notification integration is not allowed , but if you see the error is created with incident 37001. Snowflake monitor those incident and make changes as needed.
they have enabled notification integration after day, then its working fine.